# Excel: Dynamic dropdown list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dropdown

I have a static "**Roles**" table on one side:

| ROLES |
| --- |
| Project Manager |
| Designer |
| Developer |

And a 2 columns "**Name**" and "**Role**" table on the other side:

| NAME | ROLE |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | Project Manager |
| John | Designer |
| Suzie | Developer |
| Fred | Project Manager |
| Julie | Developer |

Now I'd like to have two dropdowns:

- the first (**Role**) would be static (based on the first "**Roles**" table, easy to do with Data Validation)
- the second (**Name**) would be dynamic, querying the second table based on the first dropdown's choice

Example: if I choose `Developer` in the first dropdown, I'd like to have `Suzie` and `Julie` in the second dropdown.

[Dynamic dropdown result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnucH.jpg)

I can't find a solution with this data model…

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a helper column in which you put the formula that will return the correct list based on the choice then refer to that. There is no direct way(without vba) to do what you want from the existing list.

With Office 365

Use a helper column.  In D2 I put `=FILTER(A:A,B:B=G1)`

Where G1 has the first drop down with the three roles.

Then in the data validation formula I put `=D2#`

[image]

Which gives me:

[image]

---

To make it a little more robust we can create three ranges that return each list.

I put the titles in D1:F1 and then used `=FILTER($A:$A,$B:$B=D1)`in D2 and drug it over to F2.

[image]

Then I create three named ranges.  The name was the Role and the Formula was like `=Sheet5!$D$2#` respectively.  I needed to add `_` in place of the space.

[image]

Then in the formula for the data validation I used `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($G1," ","_"))`
[image]

That way I can now drag it down and it will refer to the cell in column G of the same row and change the list accordingly:

[image]

Comment: Since when does the validation list work with spilled ranges? That's really an enhancement :-)

Comment: @Ike the reference to a spilled list has worked since they were introduced, but you cannot use the formula that created the spilled list directly in the data validation just like you cannot use an array formula directly in the data validation.